# How to exclude all numbers and dates from "_all" in the mapping of elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, numbers

I want to remove all the numbers and dates from the "_all" field in elasticsearch. This to reduce the size and increase the performance. I thought that this could be done by using dynamic_templates, but I can't get it to work.

The mapping is this (only for numbers, to keep it simple):

```
{
 "mappings" : {
  "log" : {
   "dynamic_templates" : [{
     "_Excl_numbers" : {
      "match" : "*",
      "match_mapping_type" : "long",
      "mapping" : {
       "type" : "long"
      },
      "include_in_all" : false
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

The test data that I use (index type = "log"):

```
POST: http://{{URL}}/{{TEST_INDEX}}/_bulk
{"index":{"_type" : "log", "_id" : "2" } }
{"level_array":{"id":2,"ingestDate":null},"path":"rvh","group":"U-17"}
{"index":{"_type" : "log", "_id" : "3" } }
{"level_array":{"id":3,"ingestDate":"2011-08-04"},"group":"U-12"}
{"index":{"_type" : "log", "_id" : "4" } }
{"level_array":{"id":4,"ingestDate":"2011-08-04T10:00:00"},"path":["rvh","fcl"],"group":"U-17"}
{"index":{"_type" : "log", "_id" : "5" } }
{"level_array":[{"id":5,"ingestDate":"2011-09-07"},{"id":5,"ingestDate":"2011-02-05"}],"titel":"0125-DCU-INTR-TST-17"}
```

And now I should be getting no results with this query, but I do:

```
{
 "_source" : true,
 "query" : {
  "simple_query_string" : {
   "query" : "2",
   "analyze_wildcard" : true,
   "default_operator" : "AND"
  }
 }
}
```

So, how to alter the mapping to exclude all the numbers (and dates, booleans, etc) from the "_all" field?

ElasticSearch version is 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put `include_in_all` at the wrong level. It should be:

```
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "_Excl_numbers": {
        "match": "*",
        "match_mapping_type": "long",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "long",
          "include_in_all": false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Do you know how to add all the numbers in 1 go (and keep the type)? I could add all the types separately if needed, but maybe there's a cleaner solution?

Comment: What do you mean "add all the numbers in 1 go"?

Comment: As I just discovered, [the mapping of numbers goes default to long or double](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#dynamic-field-mapping), it's really only the floats that I need to also remove from the "_all" field, so I'll just add another rule. Thanks for the solution.